# How to generate complete json string of a java instance

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a class which has below fields

```
class MyEvent {
    private long eventId;
    private EventType eventType;
    private EventCategory category;
    private List<String> params;
    private Boolean exists;
    private long time;
    private MyLocation location;
    private boolean eventFlag;
    private EventCriticality criticality;
    private EventStatus eventStatus;
}
```

As you can see this class has primitive fields, fields with wrapper of primitive types (like Boolean exists), enums (EventStatus, EventCategory etc) and fields of other reference (like MyLocation location), collections

I want to generate complete json string, that has all the fields.

When i use

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(myevent);
```

I get json generated only for primitive fields that is

```
{
  "eventid": 0,
  "time": 0,
  "eventFlag": false
}
```

Here myevent is instance of MyEvent which i get by using reflection i.e. i have class and then call clazz.newInstance()

**How can i generate a json string that has all the fields i.e. complete json string.**

Comment: It can happen that your other fields are `null`, so Gson ignores it. Can you check it? You can explicitly set to serialize nulls following way:

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();`

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a flexibility to change api, you can use Jackson API http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome.

With jackson you can write a code like this

```
MyEvent myEvent = new MyEvent();
//Your code to set myEvent
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String str1 = mapper.writeValueAsString(myEvent);
```

You will get the desired output. It will loop through all the objects withing myEvent and generate a json.

Comment: this does the thing, but has value as null. I guess for that we would need to create an instance with all the values in it.

Comment: yes, if all your instances are initialized it should work as you want it to.